# Which statement is good for clear the text field

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i need to make my text box empty while clicking the clear button.Which statement is good? 
  these three statement are doing same work .which one is more accurate?
  is there any difference between these three!

```
  textbox1.text = string.empty;

  textbox2.text = "" ;

  textbox3.text = null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, null value is wrong. Null has it's own meaning and is different with empty you should not use null instead of Empty;
You can use

```
textbox2.text = "" ;
```

but in C#, first system make an string object and then assign it to your text, however for just one editor you cannot see anything different, but the most efficient way to do that is using

```
textbox2.text = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid setting things to null when there is a meaningful default value. Methods will throw exception when called on a null object but will work just fine with empty string. String.Empty and "" are the same so it is a matter of taste.

Comment: While making null web page is not throwing any exception.Any idea about this

Comment: Well there is not always a problem it is just a good practice to set a good default value instead of null. Who knows in a couple of years someone else will come and write textbox.Text.Contains(',') and the code will break.